Remove files from included Python package in PyInstaller?
I have seen How to remove/exclude modules and files from pyInstaller? - but it does not have an answer explicitly for this ...
Consider test.py:
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
import qtawesome as qta

class My_MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
  def __init__(self):
    super(My_MainWindow, self).__init__()
    self.initUI()

  def initUI(self):
    self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 300)
    self.setWindowTitle('Testing PyQt5')
    self.statusBar().showMessage('Ready')
    close_icon_glyph = qta.icon('mdi6.close')
    self.setWindowIcon(close_icon_glyph)
    self.show()

# see also: https://github.com/spyder-ide/qtawesome/blob/master/example.py
def main(args):
  app = QApplication(sys.argv)
  # Enable High DPI display with PyQt5
  if hasattr(QtCore.Qt, 'AA_UseHighDpiPixmaps'):
    app.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.AA_UseHighDpiPixmaps)
  wind = My_MainWindow()
  sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main(sys.argv[1:])

We can create a pyinstaller .exe (and generate a test.spec file) with:
pyinstaller --onefile test.py

When the .exe is generated, we can see that the qtawesome package has been included fully (as expected), with all of the fonts it contains:

However, this example uses only materialdesignicons6-webfont.ttf and materialdesignicons6-webfont-charmap.json.
How can I instruct PyInstaller (probably in the .spec file), to exclude all the files in ./qtawesome/fonts/ except for materialdesignicons6* from the .exe, even if they are a part of the Python package proper?
